# Fnd consecutive dates withing a defined span where a Trainer is available to schedule

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, schedule, date-range

We have a table used for assigning trainers to planned customer installations. In the table, there is a record for each trainer, for each day of the year. (We can, and sometimes do, work weekends.) I am building a search tool that allows our schedulers to search for a trainer that is available X number of days between dates Y and Z.

```
Table mySchedule

Trainer        Date       Dirty (Bit)
------------------------------------------------                
Joe         06/01/2013      0
Jessica     06/01/2013      0
Alan        06/01/2013      0
Heather     06/01/2013      0
Joe         06/02/2013      1
Jessica     06/02/2013      1
Alan        06/02/2013      0
Heather     06/02/2013      0
Joe         06/03/2013      1
Jessica     06/03/2013      1
Alan        06/03/2013      1
Heather     06/03/2013      0
```

This is a simplified version of my table, covering four trainers over 3 days. If they have something scheduled, Dirty = 1. If they are free to schedule, Dirty = 0.

What I would like to build is a query that allows for the following:

- Define a Beginning and Ending Date that the work needs to occur.
- Define the number of consecutive days that the trainer will be required.
- Return each Trainer that matches, along with the first date they are available for a period of time at least equal to the number of days being requested.

**Plain text example:**

The customer asks for a trainer to be onsite for two days anytime in June. The query should return:

```
Alan, 06/01/2013
Heather, 06/01/2013
```

If the customer changed the request to three days in June, the query would return:

```
Heather, 06/01/2013
```

I've been searching for a few days now, and I've found some things that seemed close, but ultimately, I couldn't get them to work. In most cases, the failure has been in the form of insanely long execution times. Here are a few that seemed promising, and perhaps can be adapted by someone with stronger SQL-Fu than I am packing:

- [How to find N Consecutive records in a table using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725807/how-to-find-n-consecutive-records-in-a-table-using-sql)
- [Microsoft T-SQL Counting Consecutive Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790841/microsoft-t-sql-counting-consecutive-records)
- [How to find date ranges in records with consecutive dates and duplicate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839244/how-to-find-date-ranges-in-records-with-consecutive-dates-and-duplicate-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure how this will perform against a larger data set, but it gets the right results for the data set provided.  Missing data points are assumed to be available.

```
declare @startDate datetime, @endDate datetime, @days int
select @startDate = '6/1/2013', @endDate='6/3/2013', @days=2

select trainer, min(date)
from
    (
    select  trainer,date,
            (select top 1 date
            from mySchedule sInner
            where sInner.date > sOuter.date
                    and sInner.trainer = sOuter.trainer
                    and sInner.Dirty = 1    
                    and sInner.date between @startDate and @endDate
            order by sInner.date) as nextDirtyDate
    from    mySchedule sOuter
    where sOuter.dirty=0
            and sOuter.date between @startDate and @endDate
    ) sub
group by trainer, nextDirtyDate
having dateDiff(d, min(date), isNull(nextDirtyDate,dateAdd(d,1,@endDate))) >= @days
```

Comment: Works beautifully, and executes on a 150,000 record dataset in about a second. Thanks!

Comment: Hee jhinkley, I'm trying to get this to work in my own implementation. But I do not have a `DirtyDate`. Could you have a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053936/getting-unavailable-dates-for-renting-a-product-that-has-stocks?noredirect=1#comment55890674_34053936

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a missing schedule record defaults to "available", something like this should work:

```
WITH cteRawData As
(
   SELECT
      S.Trainer,
      S.Date,

      -- If there are no later busy dates within the period,
      -- assume they're free until the end of the period:
      IsNull(ED.EndDate, DateAdd(day, 1, @EndDate)) As EndDate
   FROM
      mySchedule As S
      CROSS APPLY
      (
         SELECT
            Min(Date) As EndDate
         FROM
            mySchedule As S2
         WHERE
            S2.Trainer = S.Trainer
         And
            S2.Date > S.Date
         And
            S2.Date <= @EndDate
         And
            S2.Dirty = 1
      ) As ED
   WHERE
      S.Date Between @StartDate And @EndDate
   And
      S.Dirty = 0
),
cteData As
(
   SELECT
      Trainer,
      Date,
      DateDiff(day, Date, EndDate) As NumberOfDays
   FROM
      cteRawData
)
SELECT
   Trainer,
   Min(Date) As EarliestStartDate
FROM
   cteData
WHERE
   NumberOfDays >= @NumberOfDays
GROUP BY
   Trainer
;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b3e2/17

Comment: These are both great answers! Thank you for taking the time to work it out. I accepted jhinkley's rather than yours simply because it executes faster on my dataset. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Note: I dont know how good the performance is,as it uses a running total.

Also it plays with dirty flag to get a positive number when dirty = 0
e.g. `CASE WHEN B.Dirty = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END`

It uses the number of days at 2 places in the query
`S.Date - NNN + 1 AS StartDate`
`HAVING Sum(CASE WHEN B.Dirty = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) = NNN`

```
-- Note the need to put the value of 3 to be put at 2 places
SELECT S.Trainer, S.Date - 3 + 1 AS StartDate,
Sum(CASE WHEN B.Dirty = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS RunningAvl
FROM Schedule S INNER JOIN
Schedule B
ON S.Trainer = B.Trainer
WHERE B.Date <= S.Date
AND S.Date BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-30'
AND B.Date BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-30'
GROUP BY S.Trainer, S.Date
HAVING Sum(CASE WHEN B.Dirty = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) = 3
ORDER BY S.Trainer, S.Date ;

-- Note the need to put the value of 2 to be put at 2 places
SELECT S.Trainer, S.Date - 2 + 1 AS StartDate,
Sum(CASE WHEN B.Dirty = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS RunningAvl
FROM Schedule S INNER JOIN
Schedule B
ON S.Trainer = B.Trainer
WHERE B.Date <= S.Date
AND S.Date BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-30'
AND B.Date BETWEEN '2013-06-01' AND '2013-06-30'
GROUP BY S.Trainer, S.Date
HAVING Sum(CASE WHEN B.Dirty = 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) = 2
ORDER BY S.Trainer, S.Date
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99f2d/1